# Tomcat IPath error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have a problem with the Tomcat server in Eclipse (Galileo). I already tested with this versions: 5.5.28, 6.0.26, 6.0.29 and 7.0.10 but still gets this error when i click on the server when i try to config it (the error also pop up on server start):

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.getTempDirectory(Z)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath;
```

What is this error and how can i fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to download the Eclipse Galileo J2EE version. This had the right WTP version.